# Homepage Slider stopped working

Tags: slider

My homepage slider has stopped working and all the images are displayed one below the other. I don't understand what went wrong. Can someone please suggest ways to solve this.

My website is www.barworldindia.com

Comment: Which plug in you used for slider? its look like your slider missing some html and css code.

Answer (score 1):

id attribute is missing for your `<ul>` tag it should be like below

```
<ul id= "slides">
 <li>....</li>
...
...
...

</ul>
```

Comment: Thank u Minesh. It worked.